# delete row in GridView need to save TextBox Value before delete

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `GridView` to delete a record, I have this column

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TITLE") %>' MaxLength="50" />
```

then column 2

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The delete works, but I want to save `TextBox` value before delete. I try like this:

```
protected void gvActivites_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = (TextBox)gvActivites.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle");

    lblDeleteSuccess.Text = textbox.Text + " has been deleted successfully..";
}
```

but it does not save the value from `TextBox`, how can I save the value from `TextBox` before delete?

Comment: How you are deleting the record?

Comment: Where you want to store the value of Textbox ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I do the delete direct from EntityDataSource I didn't write any code C#

Comment: @MairajAhmad I mean, now I have column1 lets name as title then I have 1 record have value lets say 'Computer Sience' then in column2 I have linkButton for delete when I click delete I want to save 'Computer Sience' defore delete because I want to use it in some where else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just You carry in session or viewState :
its onrowupdating:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvActivites.Rows[e.RowIndex];
int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtTitle");
```

its onrowdeleting : you need to set cell index based on usename column
cells[columnindex]

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvActivites.Rows[e.RowIndex];
int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
string lvUserName= gvActivites.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
Session["Name"] = lvUserName;
lblDeleteSuccess.Text = lvUserName + " has been deleted successfully..";
```

Comment: it show me this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: In your Message u getting name?                                 lblDeleteSuccess.Text = textbox.Text + " has been deleted successfully..";

Comment: yes, even I try this `TextBox textbox = (TextBox)gvActivites.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle");
Session["Name"] = textbox.Text;`

Comment: This is in RowDeleting?

Comment: Umm, I want for deleting, updating I was do it but deleting it show error

Comment: ya.. when you delete value are not go to that text boxes so you need to find in different way..i updated check once its working for me

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to a string variable before the deletion and then add it to the Viewstate or Session.

```
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)gvActivites.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle");
string TextBeforeDeletion = Textbox.Text;
ViewState.Add("TextBeforeDeletion, TextBeforeDeletion );
```

Or even better in one line of code:

```
string TextBeforeDeletion = ((TextBox)gvActivites.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle")).Text;
ViewState.Add("TextBeforeDeletion, TextBeforeDeletion );
```

Comment: it show me this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`